# Preserve hostname in Ubuntu18 docker container

Tags: docker, hostname

the docker image pulled is 80MB. There is most of the stuff missing (ifconfig, ip, openssh-server etc). You can install them later in the container but how about when you want to change and the hostname of running container and there is no hostnamectl, /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg?

Comment: You generally don't need to do any of the things you're describing as "missing".

Comment: I obviously need them otherwise I wouldn't ask.

Comment: For what?  You literally never run `ifconfig` in a Docker container, for instance: Docker sets up all of the network layer before your container exists.  Think of it like a fancy shell around a single daemon.

Comment: You do run it. I just did.